# Imported .obj has too many faces

Tags: modeling, import, faces, performance

I imported a .obj file created with osm2world, and even though the imported objects are all low poly, they have many faces.

E.g. this is just a simple plane:
[image]

but has this many faces:

[image]

Now my questions:

1. I want to export my project to a game engine. I guess this could be a major performance slowdown, right?
2. Why is this? Have I done something wrong? Can this be avoided?
3. If it can't be avoided, what would be the best way to fix this?

Comment: This is OpenStreeMap geometry, don't expect any type of clean output from there that is the expected result. If you want clean game ready geometry use that as a reference and model it by hand.